# MS Access inserting records using SQL INSERT INTO - SELECT FROM

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, sql-insert

I'm new to working with RDBs and and trying to insert data into a table using SQL from VB.NET (using System.Data.oledb namespace).  I've created tables in access database (2019) using the following SQL statements:

First table:

```
CREATE TABLE Departments ([ID] AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, [Dept] varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
```

Second table:

```
CREATE TABLE DocTypes ([ID] AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, [DocType] varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
```

Third table:

```
CREATE TABLE Documents ([ID] AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                        [DocNo] varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                        [DocName] varchar(255), 
                        [DeptID] int REFERENCES Departments(ID),
                        [DocTypeID] int REFERENCES DocTypes(ID));
```

My goal is to add data into the 3rd table.  I am able do this (the long way) by first querying the database for DeptID and DocTypeID (needs two queries) and then by running another 3rd query as follows (I'm using parameters btw):

```
INSERT INTO Documents([DocNo], [DocName], [DeptID], [DocTypeID])
VALUES (@dno, @dname, @deptid, @dtypeid);
```

However, my above approach does not feel like the right approach.  There must be an easier way to insert data into the 3rd table using a single SQL query.  I've tried the following but was not successful.

Attempt 1 (failed):

```
INSERT INTO Documents([DocNo], [DocName], [DeptID], [DocTypeID])
SELECT FROM @dno, @dname, (SELECT ID FROM Departments WHERE Dept='Some_Dept_Name'), (SELECT ID FROM DocTypes WHERE DocType='Some_Doc_Type');
```

Attempt 2 (failed):

```
INSERT INTO Documents([DocNo], [DocName], [DeptID], [DocTypeID])
SELECT @dno, @dname, Departments.ID, DocTypes.ID 
FROM DocTypes INNER JOIN (Departments INNER JOIN Documents ON Departments.ID=Documents.DeptID) ON DocTypes.ID=Documents.DocTypeID 
WHERE (Departments.Dept='some_dept_name' AND DocTypes.DocType='some_doc_type');

Kindly suggest if there is more straightforward way to achieve this.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Access requires a non-empty `FROM` clause, so you can use:

```
INSERT INTO Documents([DocNo], [DocName], [DeptID], [DocTypeID])
    SELECT @dno, @dname, d.id, dt.id,
    FROM (SELECT ID FROM DocTypes WHERE DocType = 'Some_Doc_Type') as dt,
         (SELECT ID FROM Departments WHERE Dept = 'Some_Dept_Name') as d
```